# openshift origin - using dynamic ebs volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift-origin

I am running openshift origin 3.6 ( kube v1.6.1+5115d708d7) in AWS. Ansible inventory contains cloud provider configuration and I can see the config files on the master nodes.

```
   # From inventory
   # AWS
   openshift_cloudprovider_kind=aws
   openshift_cloudprovider_aws_access_key="{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
   openshift_cloudprovider_aws_secret_key="{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
```

I have also provisioned a storageclass

```
   # oc get storageclass
   NAME             TYPE
   fast (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
```

However, when i try to create a pvc:

```
    kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
    apiVersion: "v1"
    metadata:
      name: "testclaim"
      namespace: testns
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - "ReadWriteOnce"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "3Gi"
      storageClassName: fast
```

It just goes in infinite loop trying to get the pvc created. Events show me this error:

```
   (combined from similar events): Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "fast": UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: $(encoded-message) status code: 403, request id: d0742e84-a2e1-4bfd-b642-c6f1a61ddc1b
```

Unfortunately I cannot decode the encoded message using aws cli as it gives error.

```
   aws sts decode-authorization-message -–encoded-message $(encoded-message) 
   Error: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

I haven't tried pv+pvc creation as I am looking for dynamic provisioning. Any guidance as to what I might be doing wrong.

So far I have been able to deploy pods, services etc and they seem to be working fine.

Comment: You might try asking on lists at https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo More likely to get people there who may know answer.

Comment: let me try there. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That error appears to be an AWS IAM error:

> UnauthorizedOperation
>
> You are not authorized to perform this operation. Check your IAM
>   policies, and ensure that you are using the correct access keys. For
>   more information, see Controlling Access. If the returned message is
>   encoded, you can decode it using the DecodeAuthorizationMessage
>   action. For more information, see DecodeAuthorizationMessage in the
>   AWS Security Token Service API Reference.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html#CommonErrors

You'll need to create the appropriate IAM Policies: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html#iam-example-manage-volumes